# Implement Django __iin custom lookup

Tags: django

I read the [Django documentation on custom lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-lookups/), but failed to figure out how to implement a case-insensitive __in lookup.

Anyone who can help? I'm on Django 1.10 with a Postgresql database.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need of `__iin` lookup implementation. You can use [`iregex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#iregex) like this:

```
result = MyModel.objects.filter(field__iregex=r'(test1|test2|test3)')
```

Or even a more generic approach:

```
a = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
to_lookup = '|'.join(a)  # 'test1|test2|test3'

result = MyModel.objects.filter(field__iregex=r'(' + to_lookup + ')')
```

Comment: Thank you, but if you need the lookup multiple times, this seems like an ugly solution to me.

Comment: This looks like a great way to get an sql injection attack using regex in to your query :/